# Call C# function in XSLT by Saxon

Tags: c#, xslt, saxon

I have a XSLT file in C# project like this:

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">

    <![CDATA[
  public string Test()
  {         
      return "test1";
  }
  ]]>

</msxsl:script>

...

<xsl:value-of select="user:Test()"/>
```

I transformed my XML file by this XSLT like this:

```
//Enable execute C# function in xslt
var Xsltsettings = new XsltSettings();
Xsltsettings.EnableScript = true;

XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
xsl.Load(XslFile, Xsltsettings, new XmlUrlResolver());

// get transformed results
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XsltArgumentList xslarg = new XsltArgumentList();
xsl.Transform(xdoc, xslarg, sw);
sw.Close();
```

I try to use from XSLT 2.0 by **saxon9he-api** like this:

```
 Processor processor = new Processor();

 // Load the source document.
 string sourceUri = @"D:\testXML.xml";
 XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new Uri(sourceUri));

 // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
 string xsltUri = @"D:\testXSLT.xslt";
 XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(xsltUri)).Load();

 // Set the root node of the source document to be the initial context node.
 transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

 Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
 serializer.SetOutputWriter(writer);

 transformer.Run(serializer); //Error line
```

But this code has error below:

> Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {urn:my-scripts}Test()

I read many post but I didn't find solution for solve this problem.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saxon does not support the proprietary Microsoft extensions. XSLT extensions are generally not portable between processors of different types.

You will have to <strike>re-write your existing, C#-based extension function in Java and</strike><sup>(see comment below)</sup> switch to Saxon's own proprietary extension mechanism.

Read

- http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/functions/
- http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/functions/saxon-extension-functions.html

Comment: You don't have to rewrite it in Java, Saxon allows calling extension functions written in C# -- see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility/dotnetextensions -- but you do need to use the Saxon calling conventions rather than the Microsoft ones. Note that with XSLT 2.0 the need for extension functions is greatly reduced, because you can do most things you need within XSLT/XPath.

Comment: Also note, the mechanism for "reflexive extension functions" requires Saxon-PE or higher.